# Android starting an activity dynamically

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am very new with android development. My app has a lot of views/Activity and user can jump from one view to another depending his/hers inputs. so i thought of creating an interface IView which will have a function

```
void openNewView(Class viewClass);
```

and the function in the view class would look something like this

```
public void openNewView(Class viewClass)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, viewClass.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The whole idea is that my controller can listen for user inputs and then call openNewView as per the requirement.

The issue that i am facing is with java not accepting a parameter of type Class

What is it that i am doing wrong here. is there a work around what i am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One good approach would be extend all your activities from an abstract Activity like this:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity {

    //....
    public void openNewView(Class viewClass) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, viewClass.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Doing this way you don't have to copy your code in every activities and keep code clean.

Answer (score 0):

try by adding current Context param in openNewView method as:

```
void openNewView(Class viewClass,context);
```

and in your function :

```
public void openNewView(Class viewClass,Context context)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, viewClass.class);
    context.startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: That could be dangerous depending on where the method is locating because could leak a context very easily that way.